# How to echo in specific multiple files?

Tags: text-processing

Suppose there are 200 files in `/tmp`

e.g.:  `{abc1xyz,abc2xyz,abc3xyz..abc200xyz}`

I want to write "hello" in the files from `abc38xyz` to `abc53xyz`

Comment: Would you want to overwrite the contents of the files, or would you want to insert the word on a particular line?

Comment: I want to over write the file. they may be empty also.

Comment: its just a example.
if there are 2000 files from that i want to add "test" work in files from 333 to 1987.
i cannot do it manually . i want to do it in single command

Answer (score 3):

Using `bash` or `ksh93`:

```
$ echo "hello" | tee /tmp/abc{38..53}xyz
```

Comment: @akshay Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the
answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in /tmp/abc{38..53}xyz;
do
    echo "hello" >"$file";
done;
```

might work